# Typing and saving notes on every device

Tags: javascript, types, save

I am working on notes page. I want to be able to write notes and save them. Everything works perfectly except that I only see notes in one browser. For example if I open my website on Safari, I can save my notes and I'll be able to see them forever. But if I open my website on Chrome or my phone, the notes are empty. So I need to rewrite everything and save it. So every time I want to save something, I need to rewrite the same notes on every device which is ridiculous. So what I want to do is to make my notes visible on every device. I hope it makes sense.

What I have now:

```
<div class="logo">
  <h1>
    <a href="./">Notes</a>
  </h1>
    <img src="icon.svg">
</div>


<main contenteditable="" autocorrect="off"></main>

<div class="icon">
  <img src="icon-2-01.svg">
</div>

<button>Save</button>

<script src="main.js"></script>
```

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #50554f;
  color: #FFF;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  top: 30px;
  right: -65px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  text-transform: none;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  float: right;
}

.logo img {
  width: 220px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

main {
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 6.3em);
  overflow: scroll;
  outline: none;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}

.icon img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

button {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 80px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  color: #FFF;
  right: 30px;
  float: right;
}

button, input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] {
    background: none;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: inherit;
}

html {
  overflow: scroll;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background: transparent; /* make scrollbar transparent */
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  body {
    position: fixed;
  }
  
  .logo {
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  
  h1 {
    margin-left: -130px;
  }
  
  main {
    width: 80%;
    height: calc(100% - 15em);
  }
  
  .icon {
    display: none;
  }
  
  button {
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var main = document.querySelector('main');

if (localStorage['note'] === undefined ) {
  localStorage['note'] = 'Save your note by typing in here and clicking the Save Button.<br>You can also press CMD + S / CTRL + S'
}

function siteLoad () {
  main.innerHTML = localStorage['note'];
}

function buttonSave () {
  localStorage['note'] = main.innerHTML;
}

function keySave (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 83 && e.metaKey || e.keyCode === 83 && e.ctrlKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    localStorage['note'] = main.innerHTML;
  }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {

  window.addEventListener('load', siteLoad, false);
  button.addEventListener('click', buttonSave, false);
  main.addEventListener('keydown', keySave, false);

} else if (window.attachEvent) {

  window.attachEvent('onload', siteLoad);
  button.attachEvent('onclick', buttonSave);
  main.attachEvent('keydown', keySave);

} else {
  
  window.onload = siteLoad;
  button.onclick = buttonSave;
  main.onkeydown = keySave;

}
```

Comment: You  can keep the notes in central location ("server")  and read it from there.

Comment: Yes, locale storage is just that, local to this browser. If you want to store for multiple devices you need a server.  How are you hosting your website, as that can effect what options you have.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense now.